# sending email without user interaction android

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

I was trying to send email without user interaction. every thing worked until the part for sending.

This is the sendemail function in the Gmailsender class that I am using

```
public void sendEmail() throws MessagingException 
{
    Log.i("check","start");

String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String from = "blabla@gmail.com"; //sender email, this is our website email
String pass = "blablabla"; //password of sender email

Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
Log.i("check","done pops ");


//creating session
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
Log.i("check","done sessions ");

InternetAddress toAddress;     
    toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);    
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    Log.i("check","add recipante ");

message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText("This is my app");


Log.i("check","transport");

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

//connecting..
Log.i("check","connecting");
transport.connect(host, from, pass);
//sending...
Log.i("check","wana send");
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
Log.i("check","sent");
```

}

The log "wanna send" doesn't appear..

The main activity that I am creating an object from the gmailSender has the following code:

```
 send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {   
                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("blabla@gmail.com", "blablabla");
                Log.e("check", "test 1");
                sender.sendEmail() ;
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "test 2");  
            } catch (Exception e) {   
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "test 3");                  }
```

I am getting the "test 3" log which means that the exception happened..

The result is that the email is not sent and the app is stuck... I dont know what is the wrong..

NOTE: I added the internet permission + I added the jar files

The logcat is

```
12-25 12:55:00.774: E/check(1350): test 1
12-25 12:55:00.774: I/check(1350): start
12-25 12:55:00.774: I/check(1350): done pops 
12-25 12:55:00.774: I/check(1350): done sessions 
12-25 12:55:00.774: I/check(1350): add recipante 
12-25 12:55:00.779: I/check(1350): transport
12-25 12:55:00.789: I/check(1350): connecting
12-25 12:55:00.789: E/check(1350): test 3
```

this is the whole logcat for the check tag :

```
12-25 13:20:18.698: E/check(5547): test 1
12-25 13:20:18.698: I/check(5547): start
12-25 13:20:18.698: I/check(5547): done pops 
12-25 13:20:18.723: I/check(5547): done sessions 
12-25 13:20:18.723: I/check(5547): add recipante 
12-25 13:20:18.723: I/check(5547): transport
12-25 13:20:18.733: I/check(5547): connecting
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547): [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4193bb00
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:295)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:105)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:90)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at com.example.sendmail.GMailSender.sendEmail(GMailSender.java:100)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at com.example.sendmail.MailSenderActivity$1.onClick(MailSenderActivity.java:31)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your logcat details.

Comment: 12-25 12:36:38.339: D/CLIPBOARD(31454): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... ! ***** 12-25 12:36:43.594: E/check(31454): test 1
******12-25 12:36:43.594: I/check(31454): start
******12-25 12:36:43.594: I/check(31454): done pops 
******12-25 12:36:43.629: I/check(31454): done sessions 
*****12-25 12:36:43.629: I/check(31454): add recipante 
****12-25 12:36:43.644: I/check(31454): transport
*****12-25 12:36:43.644: I/check(31454): connecting
****12-25 12:36:43.649: E/check(31454): test 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I am getting the "test 3" log which means that the exception happened..
The result is that the email is not sent and the app is stuck... I dont know what is the wrong..
```

Blind assumption, Just Put your Mail sending code in `AsyncTask`. I think the reason for your Exception is **NetworkOnMainThread**..

Also post the full **stacktrace** of Exception. So we can further help you..

**Update:**

I think this line `transport.connect(host, from, pass);` from `sendEmail()` gives you Exception.

Comment: I added synchronized  to the function.. same result.. ****What do you mean by NetworkOnMainThread ?

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThread` means, when you are trying to do some heavy loaded works (Webservice or database operation) in Android application's Main UI Thread then `Android 4.0 +` doesn't allowed that. For that you have to use other worker thread or `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I will check the AsyncTask

Comment: this what I got now 12-25 13:10:09.796: E/check(3425): test 1
12-25 13:10:09.796: I/check(3425): start
12-25 13:10:09.796: I/check(3425): done pops 
12-25 13:10:09.871: I/check(3425): done sessions 
12-25 13:10:09.876: I/check(3425): add recipante 
12-25 13:10:09.876: I/check(3425): transport
12-25 13:10:09.881: I/check(3425): connecting

Comment: As i Said.. `12-25 13:20:18.758: E/check(5547): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` So use `AsyncTask` and if possible accept answer as a correct answer. Thanks.. :-)

Comment: Yes, you can use Thread instead of AsyncTask. but Android provide a nice way to use AsyncTask. And its handle itself for you so you don't have to manage a Thread. Also you can easily display Progress Dialog for your lengthy operation from AsyncTask.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [JavaMail API](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list), which was written specifically for Android.

```
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

Below is an example of how to use the Mail wrapper, in an Android activity.

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
  super.onCreate(icicle); 
  setContentView(R.layout.main); 

  Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email); 
  addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
      Mail m = new Mail("gmailusername@gmail.com", "password"); 

      String[] toArr = {"bla@bla.com", "lala@lala.com"}; 
      m.setTo(toArr); 
      m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
      m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
      m.setBody("Email body."); 

      try { 
        m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

        if(m.send()) { 
          Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else { 
          Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
      } catch(Exception e) { 
        //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
      } 
    } 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution also, but again email is not send and the application stuck.. I would be happy if this worked..

Comment: @K_Anas: Now the question is: how do you get this info? "gmailusername@gmail.com", "password"

Comment: This project is GPL, so this will be a problem if your project is closed source.

Answer (score 2):

Word of warning if using "smtp.gmail.com" as the default smtp server.

Google will force you to change your linked email account password frequently due to their over zealous "suspicious activity" polices. In essence it treats repeated smtp requests from different countries within a short time frame as "suspicious activity". As they assume you (the email account holder) can only be in one country at a time.

When google systems detect "suspicious activity" it will prevent further emails until you change the password. As you will have hard coded the password into the app you have to re-release the app each time this happens, not ideal. This happened 3 times in a week to me, I even stored the password on another server and dynamically fetched the password each time google forced me to change it.

So I recommend using one of the many free smtp providers instead of "smtp.gmail.com" to avoid this security problem. Use the same code but change "smtp.gmail.com" to your new smtp forwarding host.