# Send password directly to email obtained from edittext on button click

Tags: android

I am facing a problem whole day but not able to find the solution. Plz guide

Tried below mentioned code but did not get any email ,I am sending new      `password to user email when`user enter his email on edittext and on submit     button password is send to email id entered by user.I am doing this work on    Forget Password Activity.I have read many Links of sending email without user interventions but did not get solution.Please help me to know what is the problem in below code .I have added three jars Mail.jar,additional.jar,activation.jar and also added files to gradle and still facing problem.
    package com.example.emailsendnoui;

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivitySecond extends Activity {

    Button send_btn ;
    EditText mail_id_text ;
    String mail ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);

        send_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1_send);
        mail_id_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_mailId);

        Log.v("hari","edittext text"+mail_id_text.getText());

        send_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mail_id_text != null) {

                StringBuilder str_mail = new StringBuilder() ;
                str_mail.append(mail_id_text.getText());
                mail = str_mail.toString();
                Log.v("hari", "mail:"+mail);

                /*StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder() ;
                str.append("ErrorName:").append("MalformedURLException :--`");`
                str.append("e.getClass").append("--`").append("e.getMessage");*/`
                String s = "12345" ;
                Log.v("hari", "Response Before:"+s);
                emailsend(s);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pls enter mail id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void emailsend(String serverresponse) {


        try {   
            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("monikacse623@gmail.com",          "abc32"); //  type ur mail id and password here and next line also
            sender.sendMail("Subject : This is Hari Testing ","Body: ServerRespHere: GET new password from DB here:"+serverresponse,"monikacse623@gmail.com",mail);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email Send Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {   
            Log.v("hari","send email"+ e.getMessage(), e);   
        } 

        }
}

package com.example.emailsendnoui ;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.Security;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String `sender, String recipients) throws Exception {`  


        try{

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new `ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));`   

        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, `InternetAddress.parse(recipients));`   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new `InternetAddress(recipients));`   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource, `javax.activation.DataSource {`   

        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }

        @Override
        public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getLoginTimeout() throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter out) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void setLoginTimeout(int seconds) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> arg0) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> arg0) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Connection getConnection(String theUsername, String    `thePassword)`
                throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345032/how-to-send-a-simple-email-programatically-exists-a-simple-way-to-do-it have a look

Comment: You have to set SMTP port no

Comment: There is a very clear and useful tutroial here : [Sending Emails without User Intervention (no Intents) in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) I've test it and it works perfectly !

Comment: yes i have entered that 465

Comment: it not 465 its 587

Comment: yes i have seen  these links and similar is implemented in my code ,but it failed.

Comment: Should i write  this, props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

**for send email by chooser:**

```
  protected void sendEmail() {
      Log.i("Send email", "");
      String[] TO = {""};
      String[] CC = {""};
      Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

      emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

      try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         finish();
         Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
      }
      catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
```

**for direct send mail, you can follow link:**

[sending email without user interaction android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028988/sending-email-without-user-interaction-android)

https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1673/sending-mail-without-user-interaction-in-android

I hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: I dont want to open mail intent ,i want to mail without using any intent.Directly send mail on button click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028988/sending-email-without-user-interaction-android  follow link

Comment: https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1673/sending-mail-without-user-interaction-in-android follow this